# Can't find wdfsrres.dll on Windows 2003 R2 disk 2?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs-r

I am trying to install DFS replication on Windows 2003 R2 which asks for the Windows 2003 R2 disk 2 but can not find wdfsrres.dll on there.

Where can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not specified you specifically need the x64 version of the Windows 2003 R2 disk 2, it is not on the x86 version.